# WordPress - save and close?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know of a way to add an additional 'Save and Close' button to the edit post page in WordPress? 'Update' is fine, but if you're wanting to quickly edit a lot of posts it becomes very tedious switching back and forth between the posts list page and the edit post page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like this on, hooking into 'post_updated':

```
add_action('post_updated', 'close_on_save', $_GET['post'] );

function close_on_save( $post_id ) {

    $posttype = get_post_type($post_id);

    if ($posttype == 'post' || $posttype == 'page')
        return $post_id;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $url = get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) . '/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=' . $posttype;

    wp_redirect( $url );
    exit;    

}
```

as i do not want to close a page i'm editing, i just redirect in case of the other posttypes.
note that wp_redirect needs an exit afterwards, as it does not do it itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that does exactly this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbulb-save-and-close/